# How to configure RabbitMQ with Filebeat

Tags: elasticsearch, rabbitmq

We use ELK to control our logs and visualize them in Kibana.
We have about 30 different log types, that we are sending both from our grid machines and both from our client side machines.

The client side machines work with filebeat-->logstash-->elastic-->Kibana

I want to change the config from:
 **filebeat-->logstash-->elastic-->Kibana**
to:
**filebeat-->Rabbitmq-->logstash-->elastic-->Kibana**

In elastic I founded this `yml` examples - when `RabbitMQ` isn't one of [them](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/filebeat-configuration-details.html).
Is it possible to config our system in this way?
or I have to use:
**filebeat-->logstash1-->Rabbitmq-->logstash2-->elastic-->Kibana**

Comment: I don't know what your options are, but have you tried Kafka as a filebeat output?  Logstash also support Kafka as an input.

Comment: In the end we stayed in the same configuration at first. Later on we started to change the project to Serilog with elastic as a sink

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not familiar with RabbitMQ in this context, but this seems to be an open issue in the Github repository for Beats:

https://github.com/elastic/beats/issues/581

There's also this post from the Elastic forums that indicates filebeat doesn't have plugin support, so I'm guessing the first option is *no*:

https://discuss.elastic.co/t/filebeat-rabbitmq-plugin/55189

Logstash certainly supports rabbitmq as an output:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-outputs-rabbitmq.html

Comment: I found in the end a nice implementation (although it's not an "official" one) for a FileBeat output plugin: https://github.com/sidleal/mqttout

Answer (score 1):

I found in the end a nice implementation (although it's not an "official" one) for a `FileBeat` output [plugin](https://github.com/sidleal/mqttout). Because as wrote here correctly `Beats` team doesn't going to support `RabbitMQ` plugin someone wrote it himself.

In Summery, in order to use the  [plugin](https://github.com/sidleal/mqttout) you should do the following:

1. In the `main.go` file:
   **package main**

   ```
   import (
       "os"

       _ "github.com/sidleal/mqttout"

       "github.com/sidleal/countbeat/cmd"
   )

   func main() {
           if err := cmd.RootCmd.Execute(); err != nil {
               os.Exit(1)
           }
   }
   ```
2. In the Config filebeat  (yourbeat.yml):
   **config file**

   ```
   output.mqtt:
       host: "127.0.0.1"
       port: 1883
       topic: "mytopic"
       user: "myvhost:myuser"
        password: "mypassword"
   ```
3. bind amq.topic exchange to your desired queue, putting your topic in Routing Key.

Comment: is it still working for you? I have some issues to build the custom beat with this plugin on the latest filebeat.

Comment: I'm not using it for few years. It did work back at the time....